# triggers are slow

Tags: sqlite, query-optimization, database-performance

I am working on an SQLite-powered C++ application and am using the basic C API for accessing SQLite databases. I have two tables RIV_PATHS and RIV_INTERSECTIONS, where RIV_PATHS contains a primary key and Intersection contains multiple foreign keys referring to table RIV_PATHS (a path consists of multiple intersections). Whenever a path is removed, all of the intersection rows should be removed. Whenever ALL of the intersections points are removed, the path should be removed:

```
CREATE TRIGGER PATHS_DELETE
AFTER DELETE ON RIV_PATHS
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM RIV_INTERSECTIONS WHERE pid = OLD.id;
END;

CREATE TRIGGER ISECTS_DELETE 
AFTER DELETE ON RIV_INTERSECTIONS
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN ((select count() from  RIV_INTERSECTIONS where pid = OLD.pid) = 0)
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM RIV_PATHS WHERE id = OLD.pid ;
END;
```

This is very slow, I think it is because of some circular triggering, but am unsure on how to avoid this behaviour (if at all possible). I have already tried changing one of the triggers to before but with no success.

I also have the same issues with inserts triggers for these table (not displayed).

The database schema is as such: The two RIV_* tables I use as a sort of view (but not views because I cannot insert/update those in SQLite) of some other tables. I create them by a `SELECT * FROM`.

```
CREATE TABLE RIV_INTERSECTIONS(
  PID INT,
  BOUNCE_NR INT,
  POS_X REAL,
  POS_Y REAL,
  POS_Z REAL,
  PRIMITIVE_ID INT,
  SHAPE_ID INT,
  OBJECT_ID INT,
  SPECTRUM_R REAL,
  SPECTRUM_G REAL,
  SPECTRUM_B REAL,
  INTERACTION_TYPE INT,
  LIGHT_ID INT
);
CREATE TABLE RIV_PATHS(
  ID INT,
  IMAGE_X INT,
  IMAGE_Y INT,
  LENS_U REAL,
  LENS_V REAL,
  TIMESTAMP REAL,
  THROUGHPUT_ONE REAL,
  THROUGHPUT_TWO REAL,
  THROUGHPUT_THREE REAL,
  RADIANCE_R REAL,
  RADIANCE_G REAL,
  RADIANCE_B REAL
);
```

Comment: There is no circular triggering. Show the database schema.

Comment: Ok, I added it, please have a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When looking up values in unindexed columns, the database has to scan the entire table.
Ensure that the `id`/`pid` columns have an index (or have an implicit index due to a PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE constraint).

In SQLite, views can be inserted/updated when using [INSTEAD OF triggers](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html).

Comment: Right, so my secondary tables / views should have the primary keys / foreign keys that my primary tables have? The SELECT * FROM does not seem to copy them, so add them manually?

Comment: Ok I added the primary keys, its fast when deleting on those keys but still very slow when deleting on another column. Any way to speed this up?

Comment: See [Query Planning](http://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner.html) and [CREATE INDEX](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createindex.html).